# regex that gets computations out of strings

Tags: php, regex

I need help writing a reg ex or maybe more that searches a string for something.

First, it searches for a string of numbers ( 0 through 9 ) that has decimal points or commas, but the decimal points and commas can only be in-between two numbers. No two decimal points next to each other, or two commas, or a decimal point next to a comma, or a comma next to a decimal point.

Then if that is found, it searches the same string for either a number 0 through 9, open parentheses, open square-bracket, or open brace and continues along as long as it find any numbers, any parentheses, any square-brackets, any braces, any comma in-between two numbers, any decimal-point in between two numbers, any pluses (+), minuses (-), asterisks (*), or forward slashes (/), and spaces in between them. It stops at the last space, close parentheses, close square-brackets, or close-braces.

I'm trying to parse data that looks like a computation and then solving it.

For example, in the string:

```
'The quick brown 1234*(5+2) jumps over"
```

take out the

```
the 1234*(5+2)
```

In the string

```
'[5/{4+(5*2)-1}] on a sunny (2 day.'
```

Take out only the

```
[5/{4+(5*2)-1}]
```

Comment: This is not a regular problem in the sense that regular expressions aren't well suited; but perhaps recursive patterns could do it.

Comment: @Jack hmm i've never heard of recursive regular expressions.

Comment: Trust me, you don't [want to know](http://sg2.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) :)

Answer (score 0):

This task cannot be solved 100% using regular expressions. Your best bet is to use regex to separate something that looks like expression and then use some other engine to try and compute it.

This should be good start: take out any consecutive sequence of digits, brackets, braces, and arithmetic signs:

```
([-\+\*/\[\]\(\)\d\s]+)
```

If running result of this match through computation engine yields error, simply skip it and try next match.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it and it seems to be matching all computation like strings except it also matches all spaces before and in-between allowed characters. How can I get it to only include spaces after a number, +, -, *, /, (, ), {, }, [, or ].

Comment: Well, you can [`trim()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) your matched string before calling computation. You can also simply remove all spaces using [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php). But, if your computing engine is any good, it should cope with extra spaces all by itself.